# How to record a complete system change in Pharo?

Tags: pharo

Given a `changeBlock` that introduce a change to the Pharo Environment (such as loading a configuration, slice or changeset).

Example code:

```
oldEnvironment := Environment current serialize.
changeBlock value.
diff := oldEnvironment difference: Environment current
```

How can I record reliably the added/removed of all packages, classes and methods?
How can I properly serialize the packages/classes/methods?

Having the names of each unit is enough.